Only plain decltype(auto) is allowed
I am learning expression templated and tried to adapt wikipedia's vector example to the matrix case as follows :
template <typename E>
class MatrixExpression
{
public:
    static constexpr bool is_leaf = false;
    double operator()(const size_t i, const size_t j) const
    {
        return static_cast<E const&>(*this)[i];
    }
    double& operator()(const size_t i, const size_t j)
    {
        return static_cast<E const&>(*this)[i];
    }
    size_t rows() const
    {
        return static_cast<E const&>(*this).rows();
    }
    size_t cols() const
    {
        return static_cast<E const&>(*this).cols();
    }
};

class matrix : public MatrixExpression<matrix>
{
    size_t          rows_;
    size_t          columns_;
    std::vector<double>  underlying_vector_;
public:
    static constexpr bool is_leaf = true;
    decltype(auto) operator()(const size_t i, const size_t j) const
    {
        return underlying_vector_[i * columns_ + j];
    }
    decltype(auto)& operator()(const size_t i, const size_t j)
                  //^^^^^^^^ triggers a only plain decltype(auto) is allowed error at compilation
    {
        return underlying_vector_[i * columns_ + j];
    }
    size_t rows() const
    {
        return rows_;
    }
    size_t cols() const
    {
        return columns_;
    }
    matrix(const size_t rows, const size_t cols) : rows_(rows), columns_(cols), underlying_vector_(rows* cols) {}
    template <typename E>
    matrix(MatrixExpression<E> const& expr) : rows_(expr.rows()), columns_(expr.cols())
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i != expr.size(); ++i)
        {
            for (size_t j = 0; j != expr.size(); ++j)
            {
                underlying_vector_[i * columns_ + j] = expr(i, j);
            }
        }
    }
};

template <typename E1, typename E2>
class MatrixSum : public MatrixExpression<MatrixSum<E1, E2>>
{
    // cref if leaf, copy otherwise
    typename std::conditional_t<E1::is_leaf, const E1&, const E1>::type _u;
    typename std::conditional_t<E2::is_leaf, const E2&, const E2>::type _v;
public:
    static constexpr bool is_leaf = false;
    MatrixSum(E1 const& u, E2 const& v) : _u(u), _v(v) {}
    decltype(auto) operator()(const size_t i, const size_t j) const
    {
        return _u(i, j) + _v(i, j);
    }
    size_t rows() const
    {
        return _v.rows();
    }
    size_t cols() const
    {
        return _v.cols();
    }
};

template <typename E1, typename E2>
MatrixSum<E1, E2>
    operator+(MatrixExpression<E1> const& u, MatrixExpression<E2> const& v)
{
    return VecSum<E1, E2>(*static_cast<const E1*>(&u), *static_cast<const E2*>(&v));
}

but at compilation line decltype(auto)& operator()(const size_t i, const size_t j) triggers a
Error C3550 only plain 'decltype(auto)' is allowed in this context

at compilation with C++ compiler from the latest visual studio 2022. I don't understand why wikipedia's article uses decltype(auto) in the first place as operator[] return (by ref or by value) a double. Is it perhaps because it was a code specialized to double but initially written in a templated way ? For sure the compiler used for wikipedia article accepts this code will visual studio's one doesn't ?

Use auto& or decltype(auto).

You have found some code on the internet, and it is just wrong. Happens all the time.

@BoP I am laughing. Yes, I know.

@Jarod42 Would you know where the norm "states" this ?

The purpose of expression templates is to create lazy algorithms. With C++20 and C++23  we already have most of those lazy algorithms; we need only compose those algorithms correctly. Don't reinvent the wheel.

@Red.Wave I think I get your point, but we don't have matrix multiplication (my target) nor elmentar matrix vector operations, let alone LU decomposition etc, don't we ? Regarding this, I asked my self if it wasn"t better, instead of modelling a matrix as two size_t's plus a std::vector, to directly use an mdspan ?

@11house - The standard isn't all that clear, but uses standardeze: "If the placeholder-type-specifier is of the form type-constraint opt
decltype(auto), T shall be the placeholder alone." https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.auto.deduct#4  Apparently "the placeholder alone" means that it cannot be combined with anything else, like the compiler says.

mdspan is a good speculation, but I don't like it. Moreover, you still need a flat vector as allocation manager for actual data. Moreover mdspan is too new. When using  and std views, be careful to not store them. These types incur references that may dangle; thus they need to be instantly consumed.
